# Where can I find the source code for Android device drivers?

Tags: android, kernel, device-driver

For example, the source code for device drivers in Linux can be found in the [/drivers](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers) folder of the repository. Where is the equivalent folder in the [Android source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror)? For example, where can I find the drivers for the GPS, camera, miscellaneous sensors, etc.?

Comment: To my knowledge, as the kernel tends to be device-specific, it needs to be compiled separately with `zimage` then dropped into the AOSP source tree.

Comment: @MichaelDodd I'll look into zimage more, never heard of that before. I'm guessing the device manufacturer distribute their drivers as binaries?

Comment: I have seen people create "custom kernels" for their phones. How is that possible without access to the device drivers?

Comment: @JetImage Depending on variant, `zimage` is usuallly the name of the compiled kernel binary. It'll either be called that or simply `kernel`

Answer (score 0):

The device drivers seem to be distributed only as binaries. For example, [here](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers) are the binary drivers for Google phones. The [public kernel source code](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/refs/heads/android-4.4/drivers/) only includes the default Linux drivers. I am not sure whether there are individual phone manufacturers who have made it a point to share the source code for the drivers used in their phones.

Answer (score 0):

You need the source code according to your phone to build a custom kernel for it. 
But, these code should be protected by companies.
Android source code is just the basic code that everyone can download and modify it. 
It do not contain all the driver your phone needs.